# FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storage, firebase-storage

I get an unfilled `UIImageView` with this error in Console

> "Object images does not exist."

**Here is the code:**

```
 // download image
    let gsReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://myaddress.appspot.com/post-pics/")
        let imageStorageRef = storageRef.child("images/")
        imageStorageRef.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("******** \(error)")
            } else {

                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)

                }
            }
```

Comment: are u sure the reference to the storage is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your Reference to the download is incorrect.
Check your current ***StorageRef*** url path, or ***ImageStorageRef***. Make sure its something like this:

```
let gsReference = Storage.storage().reference().child(auth.auth().currentUser.uid).child("post-pics")
```